# Python in Anaconda packages different from command line to jupyterhub (linux)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, environment

Strange problem here. I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 using Anaconda to set up some python environments. Specifically I am trying to set up tensorflow to use my GPU but that is just a detail. The problem is that everything works correctly when I open up a terminal and execute the following commands (for environment called `tf`):

```
conda activate tf
python
```

Then in the python prompt I run

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices()
```

The output is good, it shows I have a GPU:

> [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
> PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

So then I fire up Jupyterlab, for which I have added this environment, called `tf`, and I run the same commands, and it says it can't find some packages and only shows CPU as physical devices. This is the problem. Here is the output:

```
2022-02-16 09:20:03.656417: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-02-16 09:20:03.656737: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-02-16 09:20:03.656836: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-02-16 09:20:03.656927: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-02-16 09:20:03.658936: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-02-16 09:20:03.659034: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-02-16 09:20:03.659198: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

The same thing happens if I open up a console using this environment. But in jupyter if I open up a regular terminal and `activate tf` then it works correctly.

Why is the behavior different here? This is the first time I've seen this happen. Does anyone know how to get jupyter to behave the same way the command line is behaving?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I thought the problem was maybe the `$PATH` variable, but I enforced the path in jupyter to be the same as what is showing in the terminal session that works, but still get the same error.

Comment: Where is Jupyter installed? What environment is activated when you launch Jupyter? Is the `tf` environment registered as a kernel (does it have `ipykernel` installed)? Are you using `nb_conda_kernels` to auto-register kernels?

Comment: @merv Thanks for the help. I use a command from this tutorial to add the environment to jupyter: https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084. The command is: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf`, and then yes this environment shows up in the kernels selector and I select it. Indeed tensorflow is installed, since I can import it, but just the GPU part isn't working.

Comment: Why the "linux" tag?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt because this is running on a linux operating system

Comment: Please read the description of the tag! That's not its intended use. Oh, btw, run `env | sort` in both environments to get a better idea of the differences.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The issue that it is the same environment, not two environments. The difference occurs whether I activate the env from the command line (functioning properly) versus in jupyterhub (functioning improperly).

Comment: I'm just saying that examining `PATH` isn't all there is to it. I believe `PYTHONPATH` or something like that also exists and could make a difference.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to throw all this in a docker container and post it up here?

Answer (score 1):

The environment in which your Jupyter notebook is running has a wrong LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then it doesn't find the CUDA or cudnn libraries needed to use the GPU.

Comment: If I do `%env` inside the problematic jupyter notebook, I don't see the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable at all. I added it with `os.environ` to match the value I see in the working terminal session. However tensorflow still can't see the GPU.

Comment: You must have this variable set in the environment that runs the jupyter / python interpreter because the loader for the dynamic libraries doesn't inherit the environment from your python code. you should find out where is the configuration for your jupyter. Have a look here : https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2120